# What are the advantages/disadvantages of getting a PhD from China?

Tags: phd, advisor, computer-science, united-states, china

A Chinese university has offered me acceptance into its PhD program.  This university globally ranks 68<sup>th</sup> overall and 23<sup>rd</sup> for Computer Science.

Now keeping in mind the image Chinese universities have, I am confused whether it's worth it to pursue this opportunity. My potential supervisor has decent number of publications and experience, but he is not a well known personality in the field and just setting up a new lab. Now I am confused if going for a mid-level university in US or a top university in China is a good option in my case.

My background is in Robotics and I did my MS from Korea. My PhD topic is going to be an overlap of machine learning and robotics.

Comment: You don't get a PhD from a country. You get a PhD from a university.

Comment: Seems like this'll depend on a lot of personal factors, e.g., do you want to work in either the US or China in the future?  Then you'll probably want to consider your cultural/lifestyle/political preferences are your ability to thrive'll be heavily impacted by your compatibility with your environment.

Comment: Don’t rely on rankings, as they are highly subjective. Look at where the former students of your potential advisor, group, or department are now. Then ask yourself where you want to be in the future and how well it matches.